# Collapse jQuery Accordion On Click

Tags: jquery, onclick, accordion

I have created an accordion using jQuery which collapses fine when the user clicks a 2nd option but I would also like to have the option to collapse the open pane by clicking again on the header. How can I do this?

Here is my existing jQuery for the creation of the accordion:

```
$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex: null, });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">

    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <div class="pane">... pane content ...</div>
    
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <div class="pane">... pane content ...</div>
    
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <div class="pane">... pane content ...</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//Initialize a accordion with the collapsible option specified.
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ collapsible: true });
//Get or set the collapsible option, after init.
//getter
var collapsible = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "collapsible" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "collapsible", true );
```

Source: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-collapsible

find this demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/2DaR6/

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for the late acceptance, I had some difficulties getting it to work outside the fiddle; turns out it was an out-of-date JQuery library (school-boy error!), switched to using the Google Libraries API and it now works a dream!

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean the effect as in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WsfHu/)?

Click the selected tab to toggle its content closed/open. To enable this functionality, set the collapsible `option` to `true`.

```
collapsible: true
```